# Limit theorem problem

Tags: calculus, limits

In my calculus book, there are two theorems :
(i)$$\lim_{x \rightarrow a}x^n=a^n$$ and (ii)
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{x^n-a^n}{x-a}=na^{n-1}$$
$\forall x\in R^+ \forall n\in R.$
In my textbook, the proof of above theorems are given $\forall n\in N$. And told that "We will accept the theorem $\forall n\in R$ and apply."

I am a beginner in calculus.So, I can't prove these theorems $\forall n\in R$, and also on other websites, I can't find the proof of above theorems. So, tell me how to prove these theorems. Also give me name of books which have proofs of above theorems and which is best one for studying Analysis.THANKS

Comment: $x^n$ with $n$ being a natural number (constant) is a power function, that is continuous function and so the limit of $f(x)$ as $x\to a$ is $f(a)$.

Comment: @João but it is calculus approach, I want analytical and rigorous proof of it.

Comment: Regarding books on Analysis please consider "A Course of Pure Mathematics" by G. H. Hardy. It is especially suited for a beginner. And yes, it contains all the proofs which "a beginner in calculus" might possibly want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to understand that the first result $\lim_{x \to a}x^{n} = a^{n}$ is a consequence of the second result $\lim_{x \to a}\dfrac{x^{n} - a^{n}}{x - a} = na^{n - 1}$. This follows in the following manner: $$\lim_{x \to a}x^{n} = \lim_{x \to a}x^{n} - a^{n} + a^{n} = \lim_{x \to a}(x - a)\left(\frac{x^{n} - a^{n}}{x - a}\right) + a^{n} = 0\cdot na^{n - 1} + a^{n} = a^{n}$$ The proof of second result is bit longer. I am pasting the proof from [my blog post](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2013/11/teach-yourself-limits-in-8-hours-part-4.html) (which has proofs for other standard limit theorems also) below:

In case $n$ is positive integer the result follows easily by Binomial theorem as follows: $$\lim_{x \to a}\frac{x^{n} - a^{n}}{x - a} = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{(a + h)^{n} - a^{n}}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{(a^{n} + na^{n - 1}h + \cdots) - a^{n}}{h} = na^{n - 1}$$ If $n = 0$ then clearly the numerator vanishes and limit is $0$ so the formula is true in this case also. If $n$ is negative integer $n = -m$ so that $m$ is a positive integer, then $$\lim_{x \to a}\frac{x^{n} - a^{n}}{x - a} = \lim_{x \to a}\frac{a^{m} - x^{m}}{(x - a)x^{m}a^{m}} = -\frac{ma^{m - 1}}{a^{2m}} = -ma^{-m - 1} = na^{n - 1}$$ To handle the case when $n = p/q$ is a fraction we restrict to case when $a > 0$ and $p, q$ are positive integers. First we note that $\lim_{x \to a}(x^{q} - a^{q})/(x - a) = qa^{q - 1}$ so that the ratio $(x^{q} - a^{q})/(x - a)$ is bounded but away from zero when $x$ is in certain neighbourhood of $a$ (and since $\lim_{x \to a}x^{q} = a^{q}$ it follows that $x^{q}$ is in a certain neighbourhood of $a^{q}$). Replacing $x$ by $x^{1/q}$ and $a$ by $a^{1/q}$ we note that $(x - a)/(x^{1/q} - a^{1/q})$ is bounded but away from zero if $x$ is in a certain neighborhood of $a$. Thus we see that $(x^{1/q} - a^{1/q})/(x - a)$ is also bounded and away from zero when $x \to a$. It follows that $\lim_{x \to a}x^{1/q} = a^{1/q}$. We can now see that
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to a}\frac{x^{n} - a^{n}}{x - a} &= \lim_{x \to a}\frac{x^{p/q} - a^{p/q}}{x^{1/q} - a^{1/q}}\cdot \frac{x^{1/q} - a^{1/q}}{x - a}\notag\\
&= \lim_{y \to b}\frac{y^{p} - b^{b}}{y - b}\cdot\frac{y - b}{y^{q} - b^{q}}\text{ (putting }y = x^{1/q}, b = a^{1/q})\notag\\
&= pb^{p - 1}/qb^{q - 1} = \frac{p}{q}b^{p - q} = na^{n - 1}\notag
\end{align}
If $n$ is negative rational then the proof follows exactly along the same lines as the case for $n$ being a negative integer. In the above proof notice that it is absolutely essential that we establish that $\lim_{x \to a}x^{1/q} = a^{1/q}$ first and it requires a little bit of ingenuity in achieving this.

When $n$ is irrational then the definition of $x^{n}$ is dependent on the definitions of exponential and logarithm functions. In this case $a$ must be positive otherwise $a^{n}$ is not defined. We have $x^{n} = \exp(n\log x)$ and $a^{n} = \exp(n\log a)$. Let $\log x = y$ and $\log a = b$ so that $x \to a$ implies $y \to b$. We now have
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to a}\frac{x^{n} - a^{n}}{x - a} &= \lim_{y \to b}\frac{e^{ny} - e^{nb}}{e^{y} - e^{b}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{y \to b}\frac{e^{ny} - e^{nb}}{n(y - b)}\cdot\frac{n(y - b)}{e^{y} - e^{b}}\notag\\
&= n\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{e^{n(b + h)} - e^{nb}}{nh}\cdot\frac{h}{e^{b + h} - e^{b}}\notag\\
&= n \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{e^{nb}(e^{nh} - 1)}{nh}\cdot\frac{h}{e^{b}(e^{h} - 1)}\notag\\
&= ne^{nb}/e^{b} = ne^{b(n - 1)} = n(e^{b})^{n - 1} = na^{n - 1}\notag
\end{align}
The above proofs based on definitions of exponential and logarithm functions are not suitable for a beginner learning limits for the first time because they depend upon the higher level concepts of integral and derivative. Also these proofs make use of properties of exponential and logarithmic in an implicit fashion (these can not be proved here because of the constraint to keep the post to a reasonable length). However when one has got an understanding of derivative and integral then it is better to revisit these proofs which justify the use of fundamental logarithmic and exponential in solving various limit problems.

Comment: Do you find these proofs yourself? How you get these ideas? WONDERFUL>>>...

Comment: @user91374: Actually the motivation came from looking at various limit questions in math.stackexchange.com I figured that there are many beginners who face conceptual difficulties in limits and then I wrote some posts on evaluation of limits.

Comment: @user91374: Most of the proofs I give in the blog are very standard ones and can be found in any good book on real-analysis. I try to provide my views and probably emphasize on some subtle parts of the proof and common pitfalls. Sometimes I try to rewrite them in informal language to make it more accessible.