# Evaluate $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{x^m-a^m} {x-a}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

How to evaluate this:

$$\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{x^m-a^m} {x-a} ; m\in  \mathbb{N}$$

if i take:

$ m = 1  $

$$\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{x^1-a^1} {x-a} =1 $$  Is this correct?

but how evaluate limit where $ m = 2 $

$$\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{x^2-a^2} {x-a} =  ???$$

Comment: $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \dfrac{x^2-a^2} {x-a}=\lim\limits_{x \to a} \dfrac{(x+a)(x-a)} {x-a}=\lim\limits_{x \to a} (x+a)=2a$

Comment: You can also look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579351/limit-theorem-problem/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so if i take $ m = 3 $

$$\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{x^3-a^3} {x-a} =  \lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{(x-a)(x^2+ax+a^2)} {x-a}= \lim\limits_{x \to a} (x^2+ax+a^2)= 3a^2 $$

so if i understood

$$\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{x^m-a^m} {x-a} = m \cdot a^{m-1} $$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $x^m-a^m=(x-a)\sum_{k=1}^m x^{m-k}a^{k-1}$

Answer (score 2):

This limit is the definition of the derivative. Use the derivative of $x^m$ to figure out the answer in general.

Answer (score 1):

Nigel's hint above gives you a nice factorisation in this case, and this would be my preferred method.

In the more general case, if both the numerator and denominator both tend to 0 I would recommend applying L'Hoptial's Rule. This states that the limit of $\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ is equal to the limit of $\dfrac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ assuming of course this limit exists and $g'(x) \neq 0$ if $x \neq c$.