# Use factors to calculate limit

Tags: limits, factoring

I am stuck with this math problem.
The question is:

Use factoring to calculate this limit

(see picture)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zc1re.jpg

The only thing I came up with was:

$$2b^2 + 2bs + s^2$$

Can anybody help me out.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Have you ever come across the phrase "difference of squares"?

Comment: @GFauxPas This is not a "phrase". @ OP : please do not rely on links, make the effort to type your formulas. + Include more work and attempts, with more detail. https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/583739)

Comment: @AnneBauval What do you mean by "This is not a 'phrase'"?

Comment: @ronno my bad. My online translator misled me. It is a phrase indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\lim_{s\to{b}}{s^4-b^4\over{s^2-b^2}}=\lim_{s\to{b}}{(s^2-b^2)(s^2+b^2)\over{s^2-b^2}}$$

This question involves factoring a difference of squares, which is governed by the following formula:
$$a^2–b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$$

Comment: Still trying to get a hang of the whole formatting here, so I'll just write it the way I know it, lol.

So that leads me now to

((s^2-b^2)s^2)/s^2

I should have also mentioned that there is a little sentence as well saying:
"If you want a hint, try doing this numerically for a couple of values of s and b.
I am just wondering if that means I have to fill in a random value for b and then on the next try for s?

Comment: @Franky At the stage where you have $s^2-b^2$ in the numerator and denominator you can cancel it off, resulting in $\lim_{s\to{b}}{(s^2+b^2)}=b^2+b^2=2b^2$. Numerically substituting values in for s and b should verify this answer.

Comment: @Decimix For the health of this site, please don't encourage such low quality posts by rushing to answer them. Ask the poster to edit and improve their post before. And once this is done, look for some duplicate if it seems elementary (hence probably a FAQ).